# Redirect anonymous users from restricted areas in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I've built a web app using Symfony 2.8 and I've now got to the task of separating the admin area from the front end. I have done that using the following code in the `security.yml` file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        MyApp\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Users:
            algorithm: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:        ROLE_BLOCKED

    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: MyApp\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Users, property: username }

    firewalls:
        default:
            anonymous: ~
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            anonymous: ~
            access_denied_url: core_login
            form_login:
                check_path: core_login_check
                login_path: core_login
                failure_path: core_login
                default_target_path: ^/admin/booking/today/
            logout:
                path:   core_logout
                target: core_login

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
        - { path: ^/ajax/admin, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
        - { path: ^/ajax/backend, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
        - { path: ^/, roles: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' }
```

This is working for me in terms of blocking access to the areas I want. However, if the anonymous user tries to access /admin I get the following message:

> Full authentication is required to access this resource.

When I do this in the production environment, I just get the standard 500 error.

What I want to have happen is the user be redirected to the login page. This isn't happening at the moment, so what can I do to acheive this?

Comment: Can you try removing the "default" firewall?

Comment: Tried that and it worked, but there's part of the app that needs to access the site outside of the admin section which broke. So I moved the default section under the admin block in the security.yml file and it's worked!

Comment: Actually in your case, you should only have one firewall. If you want to remove "default" firewall, change "admin" pattern to ^/ and everything should work fine.